# put & get Vector Object in Intent android

Tags: java, android-intent, vector

i want to pass the Vector object into the

```
IntentObj.putExtra()
```

i have done like the below code

```
Intent confirmItemIntent = new Intent(this,
                    ItemConfirmSave.class);
            confirmItemIntent.putExtra("VECTORITEMCARDEDITTEXT", VECTORITEMCARDEDITTEXT);
            this.startActivity(confirmItemIntent);
```

is it correct ?  if it is then how to get the passes Vector Object into next class i.e. 
ItemConfirmSave. 
Anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// send where details is object
ClassName details = new ClassName();
Intent i = new Intent(context, EditActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Editing", details);
startActivity(i);


//receive
ClassName model = (ClassName) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Editing");

And 

Class ClassName implements Serializable {
}
```

Source [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: thnx for Reply Damith ,In my code VECTORITEMCARDEDITTEXT is an object of VectorItemCard which extends Vector<ItemCard> & implements KvmSerializable, & according to your code i have written the below code VectorItemCard getvectVectorItemCardfromCreateItem =(VectorItemCard) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("VECTORITEMCARDEDITTEXT"); but it gives me exception AndroidRuntime(1673): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.Wsdl2Code.WebServices.ItemCard_Service.ItemCard

Comment: http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/starting-an-activity-passing-a-vector-object-to-it-t1033.html